# How to get array group if value exist

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with php like this and the array i placed on loop.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 973
            [reply_id] => 3549
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 973
            [reply_id] => 3551
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 973
            [reply_id] => 3553
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 973
            [reply_id] => 3555
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 973
            [reply_id] => 4401
            [reply_author] => 28
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 232
            [reply_id] => 4405
            [reply_author] => 28
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

Now in **loop item have unique id** and the **id same like reply_id** in array. I want split every array group **based on reply_id**.

So, the final results i want like this:

**Loop item 1 (id: 3549)**

```
Array
(
    [topic_id] => 973
    [reply_id] => 3549
    [user_id] => 1
)
```

---

**Loop item 2 (id: 3551)**

```
Array
(
    [topic_id] => 973
    [reply_id] => 3551
    [user_id] => 1
)
```

---

And more...

How to make it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After first reply I now think I understand what you mean.

```
$myListWithIds = array('3549','3551');
$idListCount = 2;

for($x = 0; $x < $idListCount; $x++)
{
    $key = array_search($myListWithIds[$x], array_column($myArray, 'reply_id'));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($myArray[$key]);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

assuming your array is stored in the variable $myArray.

Comment: Thanks for your for answer, but not fixed my problem. The array i placed on the loop and i want extract every array based in array value.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand what you mean. Have a look at the change.

Comment: Thanks, you'r code give me inspiration to solve the problem.,